# Adding custom class with XAML in ListBox C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a class `PC` that contains `Image`, `Label` (with `XAML` design) and I want to get a list of PCs in `ListBox` in other class.

I tried this, but I get error `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`:

```
pc p = new pc();
list_pc.Items.Add(p);
(where list_pc is a ListBox)
```

This is the `XAML` for a single `PC`:

```
 <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="TnCyberCafe.pc"
    Title="pc"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent" Width="95" Height="104.982">

    <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,-15,10" Width="110">
        <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="96" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Resources/aaa.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.26" Margin="0,-16,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="20,70,0,-10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the `XAML` for my `list_pc`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="liste_pc" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    List PCs                
</ListBox>
```

Comment: HUH?  Would you please edit your question to include more context about where the error is occurring and what the 'xaml design' looks like?

Comment: When i tried to add a pc to my list box i get the error

Comment: I think it can be done with ObservableCollection<PC> but i don't know how exctly :)

Comment: Is that text "List PCs" inside your ListBox really there or is that some copy-paste error?

Comment: Have you considered adding an ItemTemplate?

Comment: @jure i need PCs there,@garry no i don't know that :)

Comment: Try to remove that text and see if it works. That could be your problem, you are setting the content of the listbox twice. once as direct content "List PCs", and second time as content of Items when you add the item

Comment: you are actually trying to add a Window (pc) to a ListBox as an Item.  `<Window .. x:Class="TnCyberCafe.pc"...>`. That is not possible.. You need to define a UserControl with the `<Grid><Image><Label></Grid>` inside. Or even Better, define your own PC class and do not derivide from Window. Therefore you could then define a DataTemplate, which can be used as your ItemTemplate of your ListBox.

Comment: u can explain me more plz :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first question regarding the System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:

As [Garry Vass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042344/garry-vass) mentioned something went wrong, but does not tell you exactly what happened. If you are developing in Visual Studio, Click on **Exceptions** under **Debug Tab** and enable **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**. This will point you to the Error Code.

For the second question you should have databindings and ListBox Itemtemplate as below

```
<ListBox x:Name="liste_pc" ItemsSource="{Binding PCList}"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Image Source="{Binding PCImageSource}" />
                  <Label Content="{Binding Path=PCName}" />
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

where PCList is the observable collection of PC Class object items

Comment: yes it is working but the design is missing here, it just copy the images and labels in place without the XAML design foe each one ?? how to solve that ??

Comment: Can you explain your actual requirement and what do you want to show in UI? Are you following mvvm patterm?

Comment: In my UI i want to get all xaml design for my pc when instantiate my class PC,with your code i get all objects, i place them in their places without the XAML design created in class PC.xaml